# Intersection or Union. Argument of type "" is not assignable to parameter of parameter of type x. Property is missing on type y but required in type z

Tags: typescript

I have a command class where the execute function can have two types of data defined in the PersonData; TalkInput or WalkInput:

```
interface TalkInput {
  loudness: string;
}
interface WalkInput {
  speed: string;
}

interface PersonResponse<T> {
  name: string,
  response: T
}

type PersonData = TalkInput | WalkInput;

interface TalkOutput {
  mouthMovement: string;
}

interface WalkOutput {
  feetMovement: string;
}

type CombinedOutput = TalkOutput | WalkOutput;

class Person {
  talk(data: TalkInput): PersonResponse<TalkOutput>{
    console.log("talking");
    return {
      name: 'talking',
      response: {
        mouthMovement: data.loudness + 'fast'
      }
    }
  }
  walk(data: WalkInput): PersonResponse<WalkOutput>{
    console.log("walking");
    return {
      name: 'walking',
      response: {
        feetMovement: data.speed + 'fast'
      }
    }
  }
  execute(name: Exclude<keyof Person, 'execute'>, data: PersonData): PersonResponse<CombinedOutput>{
    return this[name](data);
  }
}

const me = new Person();

me.execute('walk', { speed: 'hello' });
me.execute('talk', { loudness: 'hello' }  );
```

Check out the [tsplayground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwDYGsCSIAOArmMgN4BQyyGA9oQCYgQDOzAXMs2FKAOYDc5AL7lQkWIhQB1TLgLEylTvggR6HLjxADh5UeGjwkyAArRmNEACUW+S8wgAeVAD5FVEHAC2EDdz4ANEpQtva+aLrkYACeKqbmlgAicGBwyAC8aLJ4RCQAPsgy2DnEgvriRijo2ADyxLnuyF50YAAWALI0AG4QPuB+Wjoi5YaShbJ1YA0UVDCqYJ09fWADfILDMXEAwjReAEagapMNmdVYxwoFRef1pXoIGHCs8VAWII2p2AAU9ClwHGcSmAAJQcMyvSw2Zh2EAOZwTW5gFwzKjIBD2GgYCAAOlovC+ACJPlg+ATgYJUcgQmBCFB3ijKZ4fBwAOTEvgsoKUqghaFhDgM7nNYgdbq9CD9ZC-VK4uiMFjMZAAamQLPgXBZSkpIm1Sh1yAA7rIfn8ONcgaCXm8oTC4dcLkjBejYZicXjCUbsKTyVqqRAaXTGozvOEWZ6SdpOb6eaFYeFBZS5v7FuLJdK4Njoap6MrVeqwJruch9VR9fqIAAPCAIYgQL5M8IAUQrDwYTiwEGiNBgVssAVVlertZZLn76bBCRAyVSlvB1tjcJ2+0O9AdyN91Np7zawGYAG0GwBdE0zinFyLOrhNFCZJgG3sgL4+8g+bGDmuQL5h2ScsjKbOsq0EAYLQLLFj6r7vrWX7Er+pDUHKTCsIBwGgcWVA+kAA)

You can see that the `input` parameter in the `execute` function is complaining about not having both loudness and speed.

The actual error is:

```
Argument of type 'PersonInput' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TalkInput & WalkInput'.
  Type 'TalkInput' is not assignable to type 'TalkInput & WalkInput'.
    Property 'speed' is missing in type 'TalkInput' but required in type 'WalkInput'.
```

Obviously, typescript is complaining about trying to coerce all possible types.

I tried changing the union of `type PersonData = TalkInput| WalkInput`; to an intersection `type PersonData = TalkInput & WalkInput`;

But then that just moved the issue to the caller not having the correct properties.

Is there a way to do this without having to add any "any" types or add the TalkInput or Walkinput properties as optional?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `WalkInput` for `talk()` and `TalkInput` for `walk()`?  It doesn't affect the typing issue, it's just weird.  Right now your `execute()` method allows you to call the wrong input for the command; you can fix that, but [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) will still make it a type error in the implementation.  And for that you'd need a type assertion or redundant code.  Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpDZbm).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I can maybe write up an answer (but you should fix any typos first).

Comment: Although if my answer looks too close to one I've already written for ms/TS#30581, I might just close as a duplicate.  If that code does not meet your needs, please elaborate on the issue.

Comment: @jcalz Apologies, I mixed the name of the function and have corrected them. And yes I see your point, I think I prefer the type assertion method, that would be nice for a real answer thank you.

Here's the version I'm using with optional properties on TalkInput and WalkInput types (which I don't like): [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGkrkW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have a problem where the `execute()` method can be called incorrectly, and you should fix that before anything else.  For example, the following call produces no compiler warning with your version:

```
const me = new Person();
me.execute('talk', { speed: "iamtalkingveryfastindeed" });
```

---

If you want to require that the `name` and `data` parameter are correlated with each other, you would traditionally use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to achieve that:

```
execute(name: 'talk', data: TalkInput): PersonResponse<TalkOutput>;
execute(name: 'walk', data: WalkInput): PersonResponse<WalkOutput>;
execute(name: 'walk' | 'talk', data: WalkInput & TalkInput
): PersonResponse<CombinedOutput> {
  return this[name](data);
}
```

This is a bit redundant in that it makes you spell out each call signature, and it is also not very type safe (since the compiler doesn't really check that `data` is `WalkInput & TalkInput`... and it almost certainly is not), but it's one possible solution.

---

You could replace overloads with a [rest argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), which works the same from the call side except that the output is just `PersonResponse<CombinedOutput>` and not correlated with the input anymore.  It might look like this:

```
execute(...args: 
  [name: 'talk', data: TalkInput] | [name: 'walk', data: WalkInput]
): PersonResponse<CombinedOutput> {
  return this[args[0]](args[1] as WalkInput & TalkInput); // assert
}
```

This is more easily automated (if you have a hundred name/data pairs, you could make the compiler compute the union of tuples).  Note that the [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) of `args[1] as WalkInput & TalkInput` is the same sort of type safety hole as in the overloads (although here we are explicitly using an assertion).

If you really want type safety, then the only way to get it inside the function is with redundant code.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for the current limitations in TypeScript around writing single lines of code like `this[name](data)` where the compiler needs to track correlations between the `name` and `data` types.  Such redundant code looks like this:

```
execute(...args: 
  [name: 'talk', data: TalkInput] | [name: 'walk', data: WalkInput]
): PersonResponse<CombinedOutput> {
  return args[0] === "talk" ? this[args[0]](args[1]) : this[args[0]](args[1]);
}
```

The `args` rest parameter is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and thus we can check its first element as a *discriminant property*.  Once we check that, the compiler can narrow `args` to either `[name: 'talk', data: TalkInput]` or `[name: 'walk', data: WalkInput]` and then `this[args[0]](args[1])` works in both cases.  But there's currently no way to have the compiler do both of these narrowings for a single piece of code like `this[args[0]](args[1])`.

---

So, it's up to you.  If you want type safety inside your implementation then redundant code is the only solution.  If you want convenience inside your implementation, then you will need to give up some type safety either by using type assertions or overloads.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwDYGsCSIAOArmMgN4BQyyGA9oQCYgQDOzAXMs2FKAOYDc5AL7lQkWIhQB1TLgLEylTvggR6HLjxADh5UeGjwkyAArRmNEACUW+S8wgAeVAD5FVEHAC2EDdz4ANEpQtva+aLrkYACeKqbmlgAicGBwyAC8aLJ4RCQAPsgy2DnEgvriRijo2ADyxLnuyF50YAAWALI0AG4QPuB+Wjoi5YaShbJ1YA0UVDCqYJ09fWADfILDMXEAwjReAEagapMNmdVYxwoFRef1pXoIGHCs8VAWII2p2AAU9ClwHGcSmAAJQcMyvSw2Zh2EAOZwTW5gNwzKjIBD2GgYCAAOlovC+ACJPlg+ATgYJUcgQmBCFB3ijKZ4fBwAOTEvgsoKUqghaFhDgM7nNYgdbq9CD9ZC-VK4uiMFjMZAAamQLPgXBZSkpIm1Sh1yAA7rIfn8ONcgaCXm8oTC4dcLkjGlR0bDMTi8YSjdhSeStVSIDS6U7UUzwiyvSTtJy-TzQrDwoLKXMA4txZLpXBsdDVPRlar1WBNdzkPqqPr9RAAB4QBDECA1Gj4ZhfUMcACilYeDCcWAg0RoMCtlgCqqrNbrLJcI4zYISIGSqUt4OtcbhO32h3oDuRfuptPeXzawEVT2QcBA0WBAG1QwBdE2LiklvRUMe1yBfbFfuBQXjsZA3t4YbEpyUqmlkxTyGAt7IAUgHMqqEagTO4yQbkt5LnONphI464HEwW6IjulIAPQkXuQZHswV4-n+V4AAy3vetHUQAjDBp7mlByAAGQQXIuTksgZFnqw0BgLuAb7mev7UYxGTpJkRKyASyAAPzIFRNGyQxTFfCxV7scCyAcFpBmMcxOlGU+wyvtW771j0UC0HA9AtkBrIgdO4GAlBmEQtYq5OGc25Pm+dY1E5Llua2iGyMh4FcYJs4Bdh8aOPaRFhfZEVRTQrnuQh4bxbBqpeWBqRmtk3F8b5yVDoFfLpXhm7bsGFHvFpd4PnAvplnokQulwTQoJkTAGg1Xy+uQPjYuFkANk2XxsvFI6kMoOYcASwDeOy2hOdEBagPQOaqUIvqzfNEDLUha0bWorKtBAGC0CyJYXTiV3LeV620AwTCsI9z2ve9ZRAA)

Comment: Thank you. This is the depth of answer I needed to understand this typescript behavior. I'll follow along #30581.